# NodeJs Socket programming how to handle and manage Sockets? (Without Using socket.io) What is the efficient way?

Tags: node.js, websocket, chat

After connection to the Server, every time `Data` coming from this connection (`Socket.on('data',...)`), Server fetches `UserID` from `Data` and check the `ClientList` (array of Socket objects), to see if Socket with this `UserID` exists in `ClientList`, if not : adds `UserID` as a property of `Socket` and then adds `Socket` object to `Client list`.

So when user with ID=1 want to send a message to user with ID = 2, 
Server search for Socket with UserID = 2 in `ClientList` to find the right `Socket` and send user 1's message to the found `Socket` (user 2's socket).

I'm trying to accomplish this without using `socket.io`! That's what my employer made me to do! :))

Now my question is:  am I doing this right? Is this efficient to check `ClientList` array (every time a connection send Data) to see if this `UserID` exists in `ClientList`? if not, then what is the right and efficient way?  there is no problem with my code and it works. but what if there are thousands of connections?

Any Sample code , example or link would be appreciated. Thank you.

**here is a pseudo code :**

```
var net = require('net');
var Server = net.createServer();
var myAuth = require('./myAuth');
var ClientList = [];

Server.on('connection', function(Socket){

    Socket.UserData = {}; // I want to add user data as a property to Socket
    Socket.on('data', function (Data) {

          var userID = myAuth.Authenticate_and_getUserID(Data);

            if(userID != undefined){
                var found = false;
                ClientList.filter(function(item){
                    // check if Socket is in ClientList
                    if(item.UserData.ID == userID){
                        // client was connected before
                        found = true;
                    }
                });

                if(!found){
                    // this is a new connection, Add it to ClientList
                    Socket.UserData.ID = userID;
                    ClientList.push(Socket);
                }
    }

    Socket.once('close', function(has_error){
        var index = ClientList.indexOf(Socket);
        if (index != -1){
           ClientList.splice(index, 1);
           console.log('Client closed (port=' + Socket.remotePort + ').');
        }
    });

});
```

**UPDATE for clarification:**

is this efficient to look into `ClientList` every time `Data` is coming to Server, to check for receiverID (presence of receiver) and to Update `ClientList` with current connection `UserID` if not exists?

how should I manage new connections(users) and store them in server for **later use** when number of users are thousands or millions! NOT 10 or 100. How `socket.io` is doing this?

**later usages could be:**

- check to see if one specific user is online (have an object in `ClientList`)
- send realtime message to a user if he/she is online
- etc . . .

Comment: Try message queue technologies, like mqtt or rabbitmq

Comment: @Jain thanks for your suggestion, but what about searching in `ClientList`    part?!  Does using `mqtt` remove that part ? I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I am doing this wrong!

Arrays in JavaScript are passed by reference! So there is no need to update `ClientList` every time a Socket send data.

Therefor the Code changes like Following:

```
var net = require('net');
var Server = net.createServer();
var myAuth = require('./myAuth');
var ClientList = [];

Server.on('connection', function(Socket){

    ClientList.push(Socket);
    Socket._isAuthorized = false;

    // when socket send data for the first time 
    // it gets authenticated and next time it send data 
    // server does not authenticate it

    Socket.on('data', function (Data) {

          var userID = getUserID(Data);

          if(Socket._isAuthorized != true){
              if(authenticate(Socket)){
                  Socket._isAuthorized = true;
                  Socket._userID = userID;
                  return;
              }
          }
          // do something with data...
    }

    Socket.once('close', function(has_error){
        var index = ClientList.indexOf(Socket);
        if (index != -1){
           ClientList.splice(index, 1);
           console.log('Client closed (port=' + Socket.remotePort + ').');
        }
    });

});
```

And its efficient!